# SortedSet<T> need to use different sort and equality criteria

Tags: c#, asp.net, sortedset

I have a class that was previously being used in a HashSet. This has now been changed so that the class is now used in a SortedSet, but the equality test no longer works as it did. I believe this it uses the CompareTo function for both sorting and comparing, and this is by design.

Anyone have any ideas, other than performing my own duplicate checks?

```
public sealed class DatedID : IEquatable<DatedID>, IComparable
{
    readonly DateTime _added;
    readonly int _ID;

    public DateTime Added
    {
        get { return _added; }
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get { return _ID; }
    }

    public DatedID(int id)
        : this(id, DateTime.Now) {}

    public DatedID(int id, DateTime added)
    {
        id.ThrowDefault("id");
        added.ThrowDefault("added");

        _ID = id;
        _added = added;
    }

    // Compare

    int IComparable.CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        var other = (DatedID)obj;

        // Newest => oldest
        return this.Added > other.Added ? -1 : this.Added < other.Added ? 1 : 0;
    }

    // Equals

    public bool Equals(DatedID other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;

        return this.ID == other.ID;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;

        var di = obj as DatedID;

        return di == null ? false : Equals(di);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the constructor overload that lets you define a custom `IComparer<T>`?

Comment: I've a feeling you're breaking an implied contract by having your `IComparable` and `IEquatable` implementations disagree on which items are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean you need to be able to handle multiple values with different IDs but the same `DateTime`, you could include that in your `CompareTo` implementation:

```
// TODO: Implement IComparable<DatedID> as well :)
int IComparable.CompareTo(object obj)
{
    var other = (DatedID)obj;
    int dateComparison = other.Added.CompareTo(this.Added);
    return dateComparison != 0
        ? dateComparison
        : _ID.CompareTo(other._ID);
}
```

If you mean you don't want to be able to add multiple values with the same ID but *different* dates, then you can't achieve that with `SortedSet`. In `SortedSet`, the *only* measure of equality is if the comparison returns 0.

Comment: I want to be able to constrain the set to unique ID's but be able to sort my the datetime

Comment: @dotnetnoob: Then you need two sets - a `HashSet<T>` *and* a `SortedSet<T>`. You could wrap that into your own type.

Comment: Ok - I guess uts then down to whether just to stick with the hash set and do the sorting on demand.